# How can I get Tkinter To display a very large image without having scrollbars?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to get Tkinter to display a very large image from a url, but the image doesn't fully show in the window. I would like to be able to see the entire image without having to scroll. I have tried resizing and such but that didn't seem to have much effect. Any help would be appreciated.
img link: https://web2.hirez.com/smite-media//wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Fafnir.jpg

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
import io
import urllib.request
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

canvas = Tk()
page = urllib.request.urlopen("https://web2.hirez.com/smite-media//wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Fafnir.jpg")
background = Image.open(io.BytesIO(page.read()))
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(background)
panel1 = Label(canvas, image=tkimage)
panel1.grid(ipadx=0, ipady=0, sticky=E)
mainloop()
```

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3UV6.jpg)

Comment: Did you try `background = background.resize(w, h)` where w and h are the desired width and height?

Comment: @acw1668 if I try to resize to 1920x1080 using background = background.resize(1920,1080) I get this error: "ValueError: Unknown resampling filter (1080). Use Image.NEAREST (0), Image.LANCZOS (1), Image.BILINEAR (2), Image.BICUBIC (3), Image.BOX (4) or Image.HAMMING (5)"

Comment: Should be `resize((w, h))`.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks, It's working now. I'm using Image.ANTIALIAS as paramter

Comment: @acw1668 I think the op should keep the original image separate. with `background = background.resize(w, h)` If the user resizes multiple times the image will become degraded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `size` attribute and `resize(w, h)` method to do what you want. Here is an example, which halves the image size:

```
from tkinter import *
import io
import urllib.request
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


canvas = Tk()
page = urllib.request.urlopen("https://web2.hirez.com/smite-media//wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Fafnir.jpg")
background = Image.open(io.BytesIO(page.read()))
width, height = background.size
background = background.resize((width // 2, height // 2))
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(background)
panel1 = Label(canvas, image=tkimage)
panel1.grid(ipadx=0, ipady=0, sticky=E)
mainloop()
```

**Note:** don't use `width / 2`, use `width // 2` instead - otherwise it will cause TypeError if you get a float as a division result.

**Note 1:** if the quality of the output image is more important for you, than the speed, use `background.resize((width // 2, height // 2), Image.ANTIALIAS)`.

Answer (score 0):

background = background.resize((w, h), Image.ANTIALIAS)